# how to make a child behind parent while translatingyY of both

Tags: html, css

While previewing anything I want the child to be behind the parent while animating both

I thought the child will be appear behind the parent but it appear above of parent

My question is not the parent covering child. Its parent covering child while animating both Y-axis.

Comment: read until the end of the accepted answer